# NPM Debug Logs when deploying to Google Appengine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm

I'm running into errors when deploying a node application on Google Appengine. The build runs just fine, but when deploying the following logs are logged in Stackdriver.

Is there any chance to get the mentioned error/debug logs?
In there there's probably an error description which would make it very simple to fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: Maybe of help: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

Comment: unfortunately not, this article is about logging in general, what I am looking for are the deployment logs generated by NPM. these seem not to go into stackdriver.